# iphone - ".../libtool: can't locate file for: -lxml2"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, libxml2

I have a 2 projects in an xcode workspace. One is a static library and the other one use the static library.

In the static library I added the GDataXMLNode.h and GDataXMLNode.m files, which I use in the main project. The GDataXMLNode.h is a public file so it's visible in the main project. I also linked the target of both projects with libxml2.dylib. And I also include in the Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths the location /usr/include/libxml2.

Although these, I get an Apple Mach-O Librarian Error:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lxml2
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lxml2 is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: This was fast now, though I'm trying since yesterday. I manage to fix it by removing this from the Build Settings:

OTHER_LDFLAGS = "-lxml2";

Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same error recently. As you found, removing "-lxml2" from the "Other Linker Flags" in Build Settings helped resolve the errors. This is true when you are building a static library. You **will** need to include that linker flag ("-lxml2") in any target that actually includes your static library. For example, if you created unit tests for your static library as I did (i.e. MyStaticLibraryProjectTests) then you would need to make sure to add the linker flags to the MyStaticLibraryProjectTests target but not to the actual MyStaticLibraryProject target. More often than not I generally forget to select a specific target when I go to look at my Build Settings tab. I usually assume that if I click on the big blue project icon that the build settings are just for the entire project but it is very important to select the correct target when modifying those settings.

Early on most projects generally do only have a single target but as you get more advanced it is possible to have multiple targets for each project. Hope that helps.